# choosing between requery or firing the query again in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

i have been using a SQLite database, Theres a situation where i have a list which displays all the "name" field data of a table "table1". Now i have a button to insert data in "table1". The list is populated using a simple cursor adapter which is passed a cursor "cursor1" populated with the data. "cursor1" is prepared using the SQLite query - "SELECT * FROM table1". Now the moment i insert data, i need to update the list too.

My question is-

1. will the Adapter sense the database change automatically (i guess not)?
2. using `cursor1.requery()` is correct or should i use `cursor1 = db.query("table1", null, null, null, null, null, null);`

It would be helpful if you can throw some light on which 1 is better and in which situation. Coz for the situation which i explained above, the `requery()` command is not giving a valid result while the later 1 works fine. still cant understand what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the Adapter sense the database
>   change automatically (i guess not)?

No, the `Adapter` will not sense the database change automatically.

> using cursor1.requery() is correct or
>   should i use cursor1 =
>   db.query("table1", null, null, null,
>   null, null, null);

Use `requery()`. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/) from one of my books demonstrating the technique.

Comment: well thanx a lot Mark! but i use a code where i insert some values in "table1" and then call the requery function, This didnt workout. The table was initially empty, later i inserted the value and the requery didnt return any result. But when i used 
    cursor1 = db.query("table1", null, null, null, null, null, null); 
, it returned me the values... wat should i understand from this??
Please throw some light on this...

Comment: It seems that the requery method has been deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Comment: @tjb: Yes, this answer is from over two years ago. Either run a fresh query in an `AsyncTask` and swap in the new `Cursor`, or use the `Loader` framework.